# Flutter: Nested row in column, how to fill row without expanding parent column

Tags: flutter, nested, row

This is what I have:

[image: row with two children inside column]

source code:

```
Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Text('text'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Text('text'),
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

How can I make the blue and red container to match the green container's width without making them larger as the green container?

[image: result]

this is what I want to get without using a fixed with for the containers inside the row. Also I have more than one element in the column and I don't want to use fixed sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        Container(
          width: 100,
          Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
          Expanded(
          child:
            Container(
              child: Text('text'),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
          child:
            Container(
              child: Text('text'),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

You can wrap only children of Row with Expanded widget.

Comment: Hi, I do not want the blue and red container to be larger than the green one. I've edited my question because this was unclear.

Comment: Then remove width of Container or wrap Row with Container which has 100 width.

Comment: or remove width of Container and wrap whole column with fixed size widget. I hope it would be helpful for you:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not want fixed sizes. In my case this is for containing an image and two buttons on the bottom. The Column with depends on the image, and the buttons on the bottom should fill the available space but do not expand the container.

Answer (score 0):

If the size if fixed then you can add a width to the container which are wrap with the row widget.

The reason i gave width 50 is beacause the parent container is having width of 100 already so remaning width are given to containers

```
Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Text('text'),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  child: Text('text'),
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: That's what I want, but I do not want to use a fixed with for the row children. The fixed sizes in the question are only for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexible widget to give row fixible width

```
Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 150,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text('text'),
                          color: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        child: Container(
                          child: Text('text'),
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Yeah, but then I would have to give the parent container a fixed size. But the size has to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have to add Exapnded to the childeren of row widgets

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
  color: Colors.grey,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text('Hdddfhlsd', style: primaryTextStyle()),
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('text'),
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Text('text'),
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Hi, with your implementation the column takes all the vertical space available even when the first container in the column has a fixed width.

Comment: Its beacause we are using strech property in the column, to restrict the the container with the fixed height we can give it to the main container.

Answer (score 0):

```
 **Replace your container by this **

Container(
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 100,
             
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('text'),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('text'),
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```